# Visual Studio Code not activating the selected python interpreter for jupyter notebook

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, conda, environment

My conda environments all show up in the select interpreter path. When I select the conda environment (`Python 3.7.7 64-bit ('adv_ml':conda)`) I want and navigate to an existing jupyter notebook in vscode. I noticed that a different conda env (conda env B) is active despite both the kernel and python interpreter saying `Python 3.7.7 64-bit ('adv_ml':conda)` is selected.

Additionally, the .vscode settings.json in my project has the correct conda env

```
{
    "python.pythonPath": "/Users/me/anaconda3/envs/adv_ml/bin/python",
    "jupyter.jupyterServerType": "local"
}
```

Now here is the kicker... if I create a new jupyter notebook, when I check what conda env it is using it is using the correct conda environment `Python 3.7.7 64-bit ('adv_ml':conda)`.

Is there a setting I am missing that is causing existing jupyter notebooks in my vscode to be tied to this other environment? Additionally, I didn't create these other notebooks so it's not like they have this incorrect environment to begin with. I should be able to edit existing notebooks with the selected environment.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, if you open an existed .ipynb file, the environment should be the one last time used, so it's not a question or setting missed.

You can manually select the environment you wanted by clicking the envrionment option:
[image]

**conda info:**
[image]

Comment: I would argue that it isnt that simple. that's exactly what I do. The interpreter visually changes, but if I run conda info in my jupyter notebook its still the previous env.

Comment: @data_newbie14. Are you sure after switching to another environment, you've connected the Server successfully like the red block shown in my screenshot?

Comment: It does, but I think it's a vscode issue? I noticed that I have to do this 3/2 times for it to eventually change :/ trying to avoid have to do it multiple times

Comment: I can't reproduce your question, but considering it's an issue on your machine, you can put it in [github:vscode-python](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen) to seek for more help.